# TEdit OnChangeTracking

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I want to format `##.###.###-#` in **TEdit**, I am using the following code:

```
procedure TfrmPropiedad.edtRUTChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
var
  texto, digito: string;
begin
  with Sender as TEdit do
  begin
    if Length(Text) > 1 then
    begin
      texto := ReplaceStr(ReplaceStr(Text, '.', ''), '-', '');
      if Length(texto) > 1 then
      begin
        digito := Copy(texto, Length(texto), 1);
        texto := FormatFloat(',0', StrToFloat(Copy(texto, 1, Length(texto) - 1)));
        texto := ReplaceStr(texto, ',', '.');
        texto := texto + '-' + digito;
        OnChangeTracking := nil;
        Text := '';
        Text := AnsiUpperCase(texto);
        OnChangeTracking := edtRUTChangeTracking;
        GoToTextEnd;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But `GotoTextEnd` doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code you've placed inside OnChange set at new Text for the Edit component, and there by raising a new OnChange Event. If you move your code to the ChangeTracking Event then it works:

```
procedure TForm15.edtRUTChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
var
  texto, digito: string;
begin
  with Sender as TEdit do
  begin
    if Length(Text) > 1 then
    begin
      texto := String(Text).Replace('.', '').Replace( '-', '');

      if Length(texto) > 1 then
      begin
        digito := Copy(texto, Length(texto), 1);
        texto := FormatFloat(',0', StrToFloat(Copy(texto, 1, Length(texto) - 1)));
        texto := texto.Replace(',', '.');
        texto := texto + '-' + digito;
        OnChangeTracking := nil;
        Text := '';
        Text := AnsiUpperCase(texto);
        OnChangeTracking := edtRUTChangeTracking;
        GoToTextEnd;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```